# Calculating the values of N number of inputs using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a form where users can create unlimited number of rows (using jquery- add new row) to add multiple products information. When they create new rows the code looks like following.

Now what I am trying to do is when every time an user puts the value of product quantity and product price I want to instantly calculate the total `(product quantity* product price)` and put the result in the `total[]` input and then adjust the `total amount` input which is at the bottom of the form.

I know how to do this when I have fixed amount of inputs using jquery, but since the amount of inputs are not fixed in this situation I have any idea on how to achieve this.

Could you please show me?

Thanks in Advance :)

```
 <tr>

   <td><input type="text" name="name[]" id="name_1" value=""></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_1" value=""></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="rate[]" id="rate_1" value=""></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="total[]" id="total_1" value=""></td>                        

 </tr>  

 <tr>

  <td><input type="text" name="name[]" id="name_2" value=""></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_2" value=""></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="rate[]" id="rate_2" value=""></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="total[]" id="total_2" value=""></td>                     

 </tr>  

   <!-- I have N number of rows like above. and at the bottom I have input for total -->
 <tr>

   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="totalamount" id="totalamount" value=""></td>                        

  </tr>
```

Comment: Add your current jQuery code too.

Comment: You mean the jquery code that is creating new rows? this is all I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possible solution:

```
$(":text[name='quantity[]'], :text[name='rate[]']").on("change", function() {
    var totalamount = 0;
    $("tr").each(function() {
        var quantity = +$(this).find(":text[name='quantity[]']").val() || 0;
        var rate = +$(this).find(":text[name='rate[]']").val() || 0;
        var subtotal = quantity * rate;
        $(this).find(":text[name='total[]']").val(subtotal);
        totalamount += subtotal;
    });
    $("#totalamount").val(totalamount);
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ak49E/

Comment: You are not considering `rate`. as he said `(product quantity* product price)` goes in `total[]` :s

Comment: @Joy Ah, I mixed up `rate` and `total` in rows. Now it's OK.

Comment: @VisioN Excellent.. work :) I wish I could be an expert like you :(